# Capacitance modulation to maintain current-voltage (IV) character

Tags: battery-charging, capacitance, feedback, supercapacitor, time-constant

The ideal capacitor DC analysis shows the time constant to be a function of the load resistance and capacitance.

Since the load resistance will be constant during discharge, is there any research on modulating the capacitance with a feedback to maintain the current? This may be naive/illogical to the practicing engineers who know the in depth physics... but as a novice I wish to know.

Comment: Just replace the capacitor with a short circuit to get what you want. If you feel that is not what you want then you need to put more detail in your question.

Comment: i expected a good comment,u r asking me to discharge the capacitor or remove an energy source with a short? i dont feel your reply to be anywhere a reply but a mockery.And i am not that much novice..m too a practicing engineer but in a different segment of electronics

Comment: If you want *\$\color{red}{\text{to maintain the current}}\$* you must short the capacitance.

Comment: i am trying to use the capacitor like a battery(in its active mode of operation) not as an RC circuit connected to a source.

Comment: Then you need to show your circuit proposal and not expect people to guess what you are talking about. Put your circuit proposal into the question.

Comment: I already mentioned that i am operating an RC circuit while discharging and resistance to  be a load resistance, while we know that a Capacitor discharges exponentially and it depends upon the time constant (t=RC) R being constant, I can change C as per the Discharge rate so as to make the response sluggish with time(modulation of capacitance) such that the voltage and current characterstic is less varying. I feel a differentiator to the control of a varicap will be a rough estimation..i will supply with a proposed circuit ..as I am more into embedded i need time for that.

Comment: Nobody is going to try and remake your schematic in their mind's eye. This is why we use schematics - values and component names are important for references when making answers or observations.